# Evaluating $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int^{n}_{0} (1+\frac{x}{n})^{-n} \log(2+ \cos(\frac{x}{n})) \> dx$

Tags: measure-theory, limits

The problem I am stuck on asks the reader to find the following limit:
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int^{n}_{0} \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{-n} \log\left(2+ \cos\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)\right)\ \mathrm dx.$$
The section I am working on contains all your basic limit theorem in measure theory (Monotone Covergence Theorem, Fatou's Lemma, Dominated Convergence Theorem). I know I am probably overseeing an application of one of them. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Domainated convergence theorem is your tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $0 \leq y \leq 1$ we have $\log(1+y) \geq y - y^2/2$, so for $0 < x \leq n$ we have

$$
\begin{align}
\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{-n} &= \exp\left[ -n \log\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)\right] \\
&\leq \exp\left[-n \left(\frac{x}{n} - \frac{x^2}{2n^2}\right)\right] \\
&= \exp\left[-x + \frac{x^2}{2n}\right] \\
&\leq \exp\left[-x + \frac{x^2}{2x}\right] \\
&= e^{-x/2}.
\end{align}
$$

Now apply dominated convergence.

Answer (score 2):

**hints:**

> $$\ln(2+\cos(x/n)) \leq \ln(3).$$

Comment: For the second term $\log (2+...) $ you may use the inequality $$\frac {x}{1+x} < \log (1+x)<x $$ valid for all, $ x>-1$ with $ x\ne 0$.