# Find the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^n\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n\log(2+\cos(x/n)) \ dx$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

**Problem Statement**

Find the limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^n\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n\log(2+\cos(x/n)) \ dx$$

**Attempt**

This problem is very similar to the [following](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/871307/evaluating-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-intn-0-1-fracxn-n-log2) and I am basically going to work it out the same way.
First, $\log(1-\frac{x}{n})\leq-\frac{x}{n}$ when $0\leq \frac{x}{n}\leq 1$. Therefore, on $[0,n]$, 
\begin{align*}
\bigg\lvert\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n\log(2+\cos(x/n))\bigg\rvert&=\bigg\lvert e^{n\log\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)}\log(2+\cos(x/n))\bigg\rvert \\
&\leq \bigg\lvert e^{n(\frac{-x}{n})}\log(3)\bigg\rvert\\
&=e^{-x}\log(3).
\end{align*}
Since $e^{-x}\log(3)$ is integrable and non-negative, the dominated convergence tells us that 
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^n\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n\log(2+\cos(x/n)) \ dx&=\int \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n\log(2+\cos(x/n))\chi_{[0,n]} \ dx\\
&=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x}\log(3)\\
&=\log(3).
\end{align*}

Is this the correct way to apply the dominated convergence theorem here?

Comment: I think the very last integral should be from $0$ to $\infty$, but the answer seems correct.

Comment: You're right..I'll edit that..thank-you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative, since $\log(2+\cos x)$ is an analytic even function over $[-1,1]$,

$$\begin{eqnarray*} n\int_{0}^{1}(1-x)^n \log(2+\cos x)\,dx&=&\log 3\int_{0}^{1}n(1-x)^n\,dx+O\left(\int_{0}^{1}nx^2(1-x)^n\,dx\right)\\&=&\frac{n}{n+1}\,\log 3+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right).\end{eqnarray*} $$

Comment: (+1) Or starting from the first integral in your answer, the approximation to the identity argument also works: $n(1-x)^n$ behaves like $\delta_1 (x)$ when $n$ is large. Formalizing this idea is not hard as we are working with a nice function.